# How to Create/Edit multiple same-evel childgrids nested Gridview in C# webforms (SQL Server)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, webforms, nested

I have a table with lots of fields.
To display every record that has lots of columns on a web browser will inconveniently force the users to drag the scrollbar to the right.

Is it possible to divide each record to two or three inner rows in gridview?

e.g.
My table has these fields:
- UPC
- Description
- AdType_Week1
- AdType_Week2
- AdType_Week3
- AdType_Week4
- AdType_Week5
- Price_Week1
- Price_Week2
- Price_Week3
- Price_Week4
- Price_Week5
- OrderStatus_Week1
- OrderStatus_Week2
- OrderStatus_Week3
- OrderStatus_Week4
- OrderStatus_Week5

Instead of showing everything in one header like this:

```
UPC | Description | AdType_Week1 | AdType_Week2 | AdType_Week3 | AdType_Week4 | AdType_Week5 | Price_Week1 | Price_Week2 | Price_Week3 | Price_Week4 | Price_Week5 | OrderStatus_Week1 | OrderStatus_Week2 | OrderStatus_Week3 | OrderStatus_Week4 | OrderStatus_Week5
```

I would like to show it like this:

```
|-UPC-|-Description-|-AdType_Week1------|-AdType_Week2------|-AdType_Week3------|
  01      banana       type abc            type def            type feg
                    |-Price_Week1-------|-Price_Week2-------|-Price_Week3-------|
                       $97.51              $78.48              $41.45
                    |-OrderStatus_Week1-|-OrderStatus_Week2-|-OrderStatus_Week3-|
                       arrived             in-progress         in-progress
|-UPC-|-Description-|-AdType_Week1------|-AdType_Week2------|-AdType_Week3------|
  02      apple        type abc            type def            type feg
                    |-Price_Week1-------|-Price_Week2-------|-Price_Week3-------|
                       $97.51              $78.48              $41.45
                    |-OrderStatus_Week1-|-OrderStatus_Week2-|-OrderStatus_Week3-|
                       arrived             in-progress         in-progress

|-UPC-|-Description-|-AdType_Week1------|-AdType_Week2------|-AdType_Week3------|
  03      orange       type abc            type def            type feg
                    |-Price_Week1-------|-Price_Week2-------|-Price_Week3-------|
                       $97.51              $78.48              $41.45
                    |-OrderStatus_Week1-|-OrderStatus_Week2-|-OrderStatus_Week3-|
                       arrived             in-progress         in-progress
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.
Setup two child gridviews within the parent gridview.